# Signed WiX Bootstrap EXE can't use taskkill in custom action

Tags: wix, signing, burn

We are using [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) to sign and create [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) files and then bundle them into a signed EXE file. The MSIs are generated fine.

Each MSI file contains a command to run at the end to kill the application. In the standard WiX manner, we use `CAQuietExec` to run a quiet command (we've no `Form`, so we can't use `CloseApplication`).
This works just fine for the signed MSI files *and* also works fine if the MSI file is bundled into an *unsigned* EXE file.

However, if we sign the EXE, then the signature appears OK, but the `kill` command causes a `1603 Error Code`.

We eventually (by literally commenting out each line in the MSI WXS file, building and running the EXE) isolated the issue to the `CAQuietExec` line that executes a 'taskkill' command.

Is there a way we can get more information on this? It doesn't make much sense and ensures we can't deploy a bundled EXE file.

Comment: What does the verbose log say? You can generate it with `/l*v` switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the problem. We found :
1) .Net 45 rather than .Net4 wouldn't have the issue (i.e. changign the pre-req and out app requirement)
2) The signing should be carried out in Wix
3) Sign all contents AND the MSIs too